# Entity Framework Core with dependency injection with singletons

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to use Dependency Injection with a singleton and `DBContext.`

In .net framework I can do something like this

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private readonly Func<MyDbContext> _getContext;
    public MySingleton(Func<MyDbContext> getContext)
    {
      _getContext = getContext;
    }
}
```

However, when I do this now I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Func`1[MyDbContext]'

I did try to add this to the constructor.

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private readonly Func<MyDbContext> _getContext;
    public MySingleton(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
         _getContext =
             () => (MyDbContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(MyDbContext));
    }
}
```

However, `serviceProvider` returns the same instance

How can I create a new instance of `MyDbContext` every time I use it?

Comment: Inject `IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>` and use the `factory.CreateDbContext()`. The factory is a singleton. More information: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resolving a singleton with MS.DI, that singleton *and all its dependencies* are resolved from the root scope/container. This is why you experience the behavior where resolving the `MyDbContext` from an injected `IServiceProvider` always gives the same instance; that scoped instance is *scoped* to the container. In other words, that scoped instance implicitly became a singleton.

MS.DI's [Closure Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/ccm/) makes it very hard to resolve scopes within singletons (without manually managing scopes through ambient state), because scopes are not available ubiquitously through ambient state, as is done using the [Ambient Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/acm/).

In practice, there are two options here:

1. Either you shorten the lifestyle of your singleton component to either `Transient` or `Scoped`
2. You start and manage an `IServiceScope` from within the component's methods and resolve the scoped component from such scope. For instance:

   ```cs
   public class MySingleton
   {
       private readonly IServiceProvider provider;
       public MySingleton(IServiceProvider provider)
       {
           this.provider = provider;
       }

       public void SomeMethod()
       {
           using (var scope = this.provider.CreateScope())
           {
               scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredInstancce<MyDbContext>();
           }
       }
   }
   ```